# pattern matching an array without redundancies

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

can anyone tell me how to rewrite this piece of code to avoid the redundant parts?

```
   val lineSplit = line.split(" ")
      lineSplit match {
        case Array(cls @ TaggedString(), prop @ TaggedString(), value @ Literal(), ".") => {processProperty(prop);processLiteral(value)}
        case Array(cls @ TaggedString(), prop @ TaggedString(), value @ LiteralwithSchema(), ".") => {processProperty(prop);processExtendedLiteral(value)}
        case Array(cls @ TaggedString(), prop @ TaggedString(), value @ TaggedString(), ".") => {processProperty(prop);processTag(value)}
        case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("unable to identify line format")

      }
```

as you might have already seen the part with the extracted property is always the same.
do you have any ideas how to sufficiently factor that part out?

thx for your input,

Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I'd just double up the match (though one could also write a custom extractor) and to avoid duplication return a function that does the work:

```
def badLine() = throw new IllegalArgumentException("unable to identify line format")
lineSplit match {
  case Array(cls @ TaggedString(), prop @ TaggedString(), x, ".") => 
    val processValue = x match {
      case value: Literal() => () => processLiteral(value)
      case value: LiteralwithSchema() ...
      ...
      case _ => badLine()
    }
    processProperty(prop)
    processValue()
  case _ => badLine()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 val lineSplit = line.split(" ")
  lineSplit match {
    case Array(cls @ TaggedString(), prop @ TaggedString(), value @ Literal(), ".") => {processProperty(prop);processValue(value)}
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("unable to identify line format")
  }

def processValue(x: String): String = {
    x match {
      case Literal() => processLiteral(x)
      case LiteralwithSchema() => processExtendedLiteral(x)
      case TaggedString() => processTag(x)
      case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("value has an unknown format!")
    }
```

I've decided to factor the value handling out to a method which felt easier for me.
Looking at the code now this question feels kind of embarassing now lol.
      }